# Why is this big oh $O(n^3)$

Tags: asymptotics

Why is this big oh $O(n^3)$?

> (b) Give a good big-Oh bound on the function $$f(n)=2^{\log_2 n} n^2 + 3n^2 \log_2 n +n -17$$

I am not sure on how to solve this. If someone could help me solve, I will be thankful as I have an exam tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is $O(n^3)$. Why?

The first term reduces to $n^3$. We can see the equality by considering the definition of logarithm:

> $\log _2 n$ = the number such that 2 raised to this power equals n

Thus $2^{\log_2 n} =n$ and furthermore $2^{\log_2 n} n^2 = n\cdot n^2 = n^3$.

The second term is $\Theta(n^2 \log_2 n) = o(n^3)$ hence irrelevant.

Finally the third and fourth order terms are also clearly $o(n^3)$.

Hence $O(n^3)$ is the tightest big Oh bound possible (incidentally the function is actually even $\Theta(n^3)$).

Comment: Could you explain how the first term reduces to O(n^3). I am sorry I cannot wrap my head around why it boils down to O(n^3).

Comment: Thank you for explaining it.

Comment: No problem at all!